# Stlite Desktop Pyodide Micropip ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, electron, streamlit, electron-builder, pyodide

When I try to "npm dump" my [Stlite Desktop](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite/blob/main/packages/desktop/README.md) Project, I run into the following error:

```
 PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python311.zip/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1209, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1181, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1145, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: The module 'micropip' is included in the Pyodide distribution, but it is not installed.
You can install it by calling:
  await micropip.install("micropip") in Python, or
  await pyodide.loadPackage("micropip") in JavaScript
See https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/loading-packages.html for more details.

    at new_error (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:12519)
    at wasm://wasm/02250ad6:wasm-function[295]:0x158827
    at wasm://wasm/02250ad6:wasm-function[296]:0x15892c
    at Module._pythonexc2js (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:640895)
    at Module.callPyObjectKwargs (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:81856)
    at Module.callPyObject (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:82066)
    at Function.apply (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:97147)
    at Object.apply (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:95381)
    at Object.pyimport (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\pyodide\pyodide.asm.js:9:119720)
    at j (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\@stlite\desktop\bin\dump_artifacts.js:3:2648)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async H (C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\@stlite\desktop\bin\dump_artifacts.js:3:2059)
    at async C:\Users\A200162672\Desktop\ars_app\node_modules\@stlite\desktop\bin\dump_artifacts.js:17:2040 {
  type: 'ModuleNotFoundError',
  __error_address: 9780520
}
```

I can't wrap my head around, why that happens on my Windows PC, I tried several versions of Electron, Electron Builder and @stlite/desktop. I tested it on a Mac and I was able to compile/build it without any problems.